# Express Node.js react integration( Refused to apply style and failed to load resource)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

first of all, i integrated an skeleton of a react app with express node js, and it works good. But when i try with an existing app i'm getting from server :

[image: Errors from server]

The code of the small server is :

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

app.get("/ping", function(req, res) {
  return res.send("pong");
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have the folder `agora-ux` inside your `build` folder, which is why it's giving a 404 Not Found error.

Try to add that folder and then it will work fine.